# Query of getting distinct latest value from table

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL I am trying to get the only one latest data of each user. I am cureently doing the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT username, value, date
FROM table
WHERE date >=  CURDATE()
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Its returning all the values by username and the query is to slow. Is there any way to make it faster and get only one latest value of each user?

Comment: Add the structure of your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` with `MAX()` in a sub-query to find each user's last date. Join with that result:

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.value, t1.date
FROM table t1
JOIN (select username, max(date) as maxdate from table
      group by username) t2 on t1.username = t2.username
                           and t1.date = t2.maxdate
WHERE t1.date >= CURDATE()
ORDER BY t1.date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

mostly if you are looking for latest date of each username. Hope this query helps

```
SELECT  T.username, T.value, TT.date
FROM table T
WHERE T.Date = (SELECT MAX(TT.Date)
                 FROM table TT
                 WHERE TT.user = T.user)
```